# Spyder Console - Error ocurred while starting the Kernel

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

### Spyder console is showing an error msg:

**An error ocurred while starting the kernel**

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\ABCD\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", mod_spec) File "C:\Users\ABCD\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", 
line 85, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals) File "C:\Users\ABCD\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\__main__.py",
line 11, in start.main() File "C:\Users\ABCD\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", 
line 287, in main import_spydercustomize() File "C:\Users\ABCD\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", 
line 39, in import_spydercustomize import spydercustomize File "C:\Users\ABCD\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", 
line 27, in from IPython.core.getipython import get_ipython File "C:\Users\ABCD\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\__init__.py", 
line 55, in from .terminal.embed import embed File "C:\Users\ABCD\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\terminal\embed.py", 
line 17, in from IPython.terminal.ipapp import load_default_config File "C:\Users\ABCD\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\terminal\ipapp.py", 
line 28, in from IPython.core.magics import ( File "C:\Users\ABCD\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\core\magics\__init__.py",
line 18, in from .code import CodeMagics, MacroToEdit File "C:\Users\ABCD\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\core\magics\code.py", 
line 23, in from urllib.request import urlopen File "C:\Users\ABCD\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", 
line 86, in import email File "C:\Users\ABCD\email.py", 
line 8, in n=input() EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

---

What I understood on reading other threads about similar kind of problems , that this is due to having two python versions installed

So, I tried manually removing all python files (as I was unable to uninstall python) and then uninstalled and reinstalled anaconda (spyder) **but the problem persists**

Any kind of help wd be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Short answer*: To fix this problem, you need to remove or rename this file:

```
C:\Users\ABCD\email.py
```

*Long answer*: That file has the same name of a core Python module. Since it's placed in your home directory, it has higher priority than that module, which makes Python to use it first and ends up causing the error.